# Can't use function return value in write context in word press

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My apologies for asking a repetitive question but my website is down and i need to get it back up.

```html
// Default stretch setting to theme setting.
 $slider_stretch = siteorigin_setting( 'home_slider_stretch' );
 if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, 'vantage_metaslider_slider_stretch' ) ) {
  $slider_stretch = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vantage_metaslider_slider_stretch', true);
 }
 $slider_can_stretch = ! empty( preg_match( '/^(demo|meta:)/', $slider ) );
 
 wp_enqueue_script(
  'siteorigin-vantage-sliders',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/sliders/js/sliders' . SITEORIGIN_THEME_JS_PREFIX . '.js',
  array( 'jquery' ),
  SITEORIGIN_THEME_VERSION
 );
```

The Website is showing error on line 112 which is $slider_can_stretch = ! empty( preg_match( '/^(demo|meta:)/', $slider ) );

Thanks

Comment: Is this javascript? `preg_match` is a PHP function, as far as I know.   What error message are you seeing, specifically?

Comment: When i hit  the website i get... Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home4/aostwinkle/public_html/osogoodwinery.com/wp-content/themes/vantage/inc/sliders.php on line 112